# What should be expected value when using 2 different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was given a question in class saying 'What are the possible final values of a? (Assume that each statement is a unit of execution. You do not need to consider the problem at the instruction level.)'. With additional information:

Thread A: a = 3 (A1) and a = a + 1 (A2)

Thread B: a = 5 (B1) and a = a + 7 (B2)

So after some thought that First thread output should be 4 and second threads output should be 12.

So I did the test script to see if that's correct and output shows what I expected Thread A: 4 and Thread B: 12.

The question is, should I expect other values? Or maybe I'm just implementing this question wrong? How I can tweak this code to get other values, if possible? Is that a tricky question, or its just me?

EDIT: Since code was not really needed for my homework assignment, lets focus on theoretical implementation of such problem.

Comment: You're not making any calls in the `run() {}` method, so your code is not useful. Everything is being done on one and only one thread.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize. Let me fix it, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you do fix your code to correctly implement threading, given today's CPU speeds and the overhead of starting threads/scheduling I bet you won't see any concurrency bugs, because either the first thread or the second one will finish their update of `a` before the other one has a chance to start, so you'll probably always get 4 and 12 as results.

You'll need much more lengthy tasks for a data-race to occur.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever correct this so it really exhibits threading rather than sequential execution, the correct answer would be that in the absence of any kind of synchronization the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Your calls to `FirstThread` and `SecondThread` are running on the main thread, not `threadA` or `threadB`.  Also, the `run()` method does nothing.

Any references to threading in this problem are merely misdirection (noise) and have nothing to do with the output.

(Also the method names `FirstThread` and `SecondThread` should start with a lowercase letter to match Java convention)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the code you give was not given as part of the homework question but rather represents you attempt to answer it. Given that, as Tudor already points out even in a correct implementation you might not see any "surprising" values, even if you run the program a few hundred times. Concurrency bugs are hard to find by testing.

My hint for understanding the correct answer is the following: 
Consider you are cooking two dishes for dinner with your loved one. You can cook the (spicy) main dish first and the (sweet) desert afterwards. (No threading). Or you cook them at the same time, switching between the two recipes. Both of them might refer to a pan (initially filled with air), one tells you to replace the content of your pan with eggs, the other to replace the content with oil and then add spices. Because you are a bad cook (you didn't learn about synchronization yet) you start by putting in oil, then replace everything in it by eggs, add sugar and then return to the first recipe and add spices ... what will it taste like?

Answer (score -1):

> > > You can get other values but you need to do something to make the program do because something with thread is random and it's hard to control.you can try my code i think there's something wrong in your code, but i don't change it, ok?

```
public class Threads implements Runnable
{
    int a = 0;

    public void run() { }

    public int FirstThread()
    {
        a = 3;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        a = a + 1;

        return a;
    }

    public int SecondThread()
    {
        a = 5;
        a = a + 7;

        return a;
    }
}
```

or use this one

```
public class Threads implements Runnable
{
    int a = 0;

    public void run() { }

    public int FirstThread()
    {
        a = 3;
        a = a + 1;

        return a;
    }

    public int SecondThread()
    {
        a = 5;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        a = a + 7;

        return a;
    }
}
```

just try it!!!

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that i hava made something wrong.Maybe the way you to try this problem is improper. I think you should build two thread class or two runnable interface implement class and add the sleep() funtion.

Comment: You should edit your answer when you want to change your advice to the questioner.